# New Button of the Command Button Group isn't working on axapta

Tags: button, command, axapta, x++

I have 2 company on Axapta. I am following this way.

`Accounts Payable -> Journals -> Invoice -> Invoice` Journal then I am clicking `create a new record`. this working at one of the companies.

But I am trying for the another company. It doesn't work. Axapta isn't responding. Why is Axapta doing this?

Can you help me?

Comment: Does your form have any customization?

Comment: Yes, we did customization. But we just put a button

Comment: Can share your code?

Comment: there isn't different code. We didn't change at code. We put a button. But we call the another form when the button click just that

Comment: What form? Does this happen on all machines?

Comment: The form is LedgerJournalTable.  And this is happening on all machine

Comment: Try to remove all customizations from the form and check if the behavior persists. If yes, it may be a standard bug or some parameter or security setting. If not, the issue is caused by the customization. Try to add the customizations to the form again little by little to determine which customization causes the issue.

Comment: Thank you. We solved this problem. Problem was about Number sequence